# while connecting directly to the db2 database thru oracle it connects but when connected thru java code throws exception

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

Hi I am getting below exception when i try to connect DB2 server thru java

com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ao: [jcc][t4][2010][11246][3.53.70] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000

When I tried connecting the DB2 using SQL Developer (With jars added in Third Party tool) the connection was successful. 
I included all the required db2jcc,db2jcc4 and db2jcc_license jar files in the project. But it throws exception.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:db2://myhost:portNumber/dbname";                
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "uname","password"); 
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

3.53.70 driver version corresponds to quite an old 9.5.3 db2 version.
You should try to download a jdbc driver corresponding to your db2 version.
[DB2 JDBC Driver Versions and Downloads](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866)

Comment: Hi I added db2jcc4.jar to the build path eventhough I am getting the same error.

Comment: What's your DB2 version? What's the driver version you downloaded and use? What's the result of the following query? `select name, value
from sysibmadm.dbmcfg
where name like '%plugin' or name like '%auth%'`